# Schedule a snapshot of a MySQL Table

Tags: mysql, snapshot, schedule

It is possible to schedule a snapshot of a MySQL table?

The situation:

I have a table that collects votes (up and down) from a website. It registers the number of votes (that can be either a vote up, “+1”, or a vote down, “-1”), and records the score (for example, if one ID received 5 votes, 3 voting "up" (+1) and 2 voting "down" (-1), then the table would record that number of votes was "5", and that the vote score was "2". It is recorded in a table that has the following column headers/fields:

ID | Score | nvotes

…where ID is the reference of the item being voted on; 'score' is the actual score that is calculated (from the number of “+1” and “-1” votes), and 'nvotes' is the number of votes that have been received

This is great for looking at the website at any point in time and seeing what the score is, and how many people have voted.

However, I now want to be able to chart the trend for the ID – to look back over time and see how the score has gone up and down over time.

Is there a facility in MySQL to be able to take a snapshot at the end of each day, recording where that particular ID was at the end of that day in terms of their score and the number of votes received, and store this in another table so that I can create charts and analysis over time?

Or, failing that, can anyone think of a better, more intelligent way of trying to acheive what I need?

Comment: You can add a date field to the table, also you can copy the scores to a new table every day with the date

Comment: How do I copy the scores every day?

Comment: make that eff dated row and you can calculate sum for votes based on dates

Comment: You can use MySQL events to update the new table at a certain time every day http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html

Comment: In continuation, I have no upgraded to the latest version of MySQL, and I'm able to create scheduled events. However, they don't seem to be working (i.e. nothing seems to be happening!). Could anyone debug the following for me:

CREATE EVENT historysched
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 24 hour
    STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 minute
DO
Insert into tablehistory (item, reference)
select item, reference
from table1
END